# Service Fabric Breakpoints Not Working

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric

I have a service fabric project with 3 applications.  When I start debugging in VS, the breakpoints activate as if they're being found, but they're never hit during execution.  I've verified that the service fabric project is the only startup project.

Comment: Can you do a "Clean Solution" on the solution file? Also the startup should be the SF application project.

Comment: Can you confirm that your services are running? If you have any EventSource logging in RunAsync for instance you should be able to see that in The Diagnostics Events view in VS (make sure you have the Event Provider for your service included). You could also just add an additional ServiceEventSource.CurrentLog("hello") close to where you have have the breakpoint that is not hit. What does that show you? If that doesn't show up in the Diagnostics Event view then your service is probably not running like you think it is, or you are not attached to the right process.

Answer (score 0):

Your breakpoint is only active when the symnbol file is loaded. Please make sure that is loaded in Modules Windows in VS

Comment: Fun fact: when debugging a Release build configuration you're not going to get symbols loading. :D Make sure you're actually debugging a Debug build.